# How can I handle a division by zero within this case statement

Tags: sql, division, handle, zero

Within this case statement I have a "divide by". How can I modify this to handle div by zero errors?

```
CASE WHEN INVOICE_V.INVC_TYPE = 0 then 
    (((INVC_ITEM_V.PRICE - INVC_ITEM_V.TAX_AMT)*INVC_ITEM_V.QTY) -  
     (INVC_ITEM_V.COST * INVC_ITEM_V.QTY)) 
        / ((INVC_ITEM_V.PRICE - INVC_ITEM_V.TAX_AMT)*INVC_ITEM_V.QTY)*100 
    else 0 END as EXT_M_PERCENT,
```

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Um, what?  Normally it throws some sort of [divide-by-zero error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=486a26402969f36ee4699b13c69eeae2), like just about every language out there.  Unless you're thinking of some specific db?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Yeah, sorry, scratch that - brainf*...

Answer (score 1):

If by "handle" you mean return 0, then you can do this:

```
CASE WHEN INVOICE_V.INVC_TYPE = 0 
      AND (((INVC_ITEM_V.PRICE - INVC_ITEM_V.TAX_AMT)*INVC_ITEM_V.QTY) <> 0 THEN
```

Comment: Yes by handle I mean return zero to prevent a division by zero error.
So basically what I wish to say is "evaluate the "divide by" and return 0 if it's 0 else continue"

Comment: @FraserKelly -- then you should accept my answer as solving your problem.